# Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider with NoSQL with Hibernate OGM

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-ogm

I'm following the tutorial given on this link: http://blog.eisele.net/2015/01/nosql-with-hibernate-ogm-part-one.html.

Getting the below error:
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.

My persistence.xml is:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence:persistence version="2.0" xmlns:persistence="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
<persistence:persistence-unit name="FootBallMan" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <persistence:provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</persistence:provider>
    <persistence:properties>
        <persistence:property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="neo4j_embedded" />
        <persistence:property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="FootBallManDB" />
        <persistence:property name="hibernate.ogm.neo4j.database_path" value="target/test_data_dir" />
    </persistence:properties>
  </persistence:persistence-unit>
</persistence:persistence>`

I have gone through a lots of similar questions but none of them mentions how to solve this problem when working with Hibernate OGM, using NoSQL Neo4j Database.

I know problem is because of using the :

```
<persistence:provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</persistence:provider>
```

HibernateOgmPersistence uses the deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider.

But I don't know how to solve it.
Please help me in solving this probelm.

Comment: which version of OGM you are using?

Comment: Using the following version: 4.2.0.Final.

Comment: Its just WARNING, you post stack trace. Btw are using spring?

Comment: @KarthikPrasad Actually, I was testing the connectivity of Hibernate OGM using Java (as mentioned in the above link). I'm trying to use the Neo4J (also tried with MongoDB). Getting the same error message (Warning) while running the JUnit test. It stops as soon as it encounters this warning.